# PHP array to JSON plotting column chart with Google Chart Tools

Tags: php, json, api

I've already read multiple questions/answers here and on other websites but I just can't get it to work.

I have a database containing Date and Count. With PHP I've constructed a nested array which when encoded becomes valid json. At least according to http://jsonlint.com/. The json (from what I can see) looks like the ones on https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example.

The only thing I'm trying to do is create a column chart with Google API (shouldn't be so hard)... I want Count (quantity) on the y-axis and the date on the x-axis.

Here's one json output example (believe me I've tried several):

> {"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Date","type":"date"},{"id":"","label":"Count","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-08"},{"v":"13"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-09"},{"v":"80"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-10"},{"v":"2021"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-11"},{"v":"18"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-12"},{"v":"8"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-13"},{"v":"4"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-14"},{"v":"687"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-15"},{"v":"6674"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-16"},{"v":"656"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-17"},{"v":"646"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-18"},{"v":"672"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-19"},{"v":"656"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-20"},{"v":"653"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-21"},{"v":"697"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-22"},{"v":"696"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-23"},{"v":"679"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-24"},{"v":"647"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-25"},{"v":"638"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-26"},{"v":"636"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-27"},{"v":"629"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-02-28"},{"v":"644"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-01"},{"v":"5648"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-02"},{"v":"4378"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-03"},{"v":"664"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-04"},{"v":"663"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-05"},{"v":"630"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-06"},{"v":"640"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-07"},{"v":"16"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-08"},{"v":"25"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-09"},{"v":"31"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-10"},{"v":"324"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-11"},{"v":"9"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-12"},{"v":"22"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-13"},{"v":"23"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-14"},{"v":"31"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-15"},{"v":"29"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-16"},{"v":"40"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-17"},{"v":"15"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-18"},{"v":"5"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-19"},{"v":"13"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-20"},{"v":"24"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-21"},{"v":"53"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-22"},{"v":"808"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-23"},{"v":"59"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-24"},{"v":"24"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-25"},{"v":"2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-26"},{"v":"16"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-27"},{"v":"1546"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-28"},{"v":"1554"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-29"},{"v":"1587"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-30"},{"v":"1570"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-03-31"},{"v":"1552"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-01"},{"v":"1559"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-02"},{"v":"1568"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-03"},{"v":"1566"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-04"},{"v":"1574"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-05"},{"v":"1558"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-06"},{"v":"1626"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-07"},{"v":"1562"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-08"},{"v":"1536"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-09"},{"v":"1565"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-10"},{"v":"1551"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-11"},{"v":"1547"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-12"},{"v":"1628"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-13"},{"v":"1541"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-14"},{"v":"1515"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-15"},{"v":"1537"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-16"},{"v":"1536"}]}]}

And the API script

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "chartjson.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
}
```

I'm at the point where I'm seriously considering making the charts in excel and upload screenshots everyday.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Am I even close (don't be mean)?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Feeling a bit stupid... After some more digging I found out that I had to use 'string' for the dates rather than dates which then solved the whole issue.